# How much trust should I put into pdb line numbers?

Tags: windows, windbg

I'm debugging a problem at present in Windbg from a dump.  I've got the correct pdbs and I can view the locals etc quite happily.  However, the source code I have (which I've pulled from the VCS branch from which this release supposedly came from) appears to be off by several lines in some parts of the stack I'm looking at.  I've seen instances where it's off by 1 before, but not 3/4 lines.

What causes this?  Is there any definitive way I can check that I've got the right source files?

Comment: Were the binaries built with optimizations?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yes they were built with /O2

Comment: Then you can't depend on line numbers.  Also be prepared for the debugger to often be confused about locals.  If you want to debug this, you should keep your eye on the disassembly so you can see what's really going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking at debug or non optimised version of release code?
Code optimisation may cause the line shift you are seeing so you should recompile with [/Od](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/hardware/ff540664%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) C++ optimization set to 'disabled' and see if this corrects what you see.

WinDbg uses the same method as Visual Studio to check if the source file you are viewing/setting breakpoints with matches the pdbs so it should warn you (I think it does this I cannot verify).

Besides you can verify the pdbs if not the source files using:

```
!itoldyouso myDLL
```

additionally you can open the source file in another window, during stepping and it should put a magenta line at the line it thinks the current call is at, this should be correct and behave the same as visual studio.

Comment: Interestingly it looked exactly the same without optimization.  I'm wondering if the quoted line number is actually showing what the return pointer is pointing at...  which sometimes doesn't give you the line which is currently being processed.

Comment: @Benj what happens if you open the source file, and start stepping, does it place the highlighted line at the correct place? That is interesting what you state.

Comment: @benj are you looking at a stack trace? In that case I believe you are correct in that the line shown is the return address on the stack.

Comment: @MarcSherman Thanks, I'm actually looking at the source code and what windbg chooses to highlight as the current line.  However, it looks identical to what's shown when you `kv`.